# Incomplete IBAN used in bank transfer

Tags: money-transfer, switzerland, iban

A transfer form a client listed only 7 digits of my IBAN (and 1 in error), the clearing number, my name and bank address are all correct. The clients account has been debited but mine has not been credited. Where can the money have gone? Transfer within Switzerland. Different banks.

Comment: Best to inquire with the Bank. Normally a transfer with a partial IBAN should not be carried out at  all, because usually the last digits carry some sort of checksum. Are you sure your client is not bullshitting you?

Comment: I thought a transfer couldn't happen without the complete IBAN as well. I  think the client is genuine. I'll check with my bank but don't expect to do anything other than confirm that there has been no payment made. I can show them the payment order that the client made with their own bank.

Comment: Client needs to inquire with their bank and try to get the erroneous transfer cancelled. nothing you can do as the money did not make it into your sphere of influence.

Comment: the person who **sent the money** must **urgently** enquire with the bank.   this is very, very unusual within Switzerland - all forms, etc, ensure the numbers are in good order.  sounds strange.

Comment: Thanks Fattie, you were right, the transfer didn't get authorised so didn't happen!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to rectify bank transfer with incomplete IBAN](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/154006/how-to-rectify-bank-transfer-with-incomplete-iban)