# How to rectify bank transfer with incomplete IBAN

Tags: banking

I sent a bank transfer with an incomplete IBAN number. How do I rectify this? It was from a trading account to a bank account, both in my name.

Comment: You should ask your bank/broker's customer support.

Comment: @0xFEE1DEAD: Short as it is, I think that's a legitimate Answer. (There have been grumbles recently about people answering in comments; I'm trying to be better about that myself )

Comment: @keshlam I think the question should be closed but I'm happy to post my comment as the (obvious) answer.

Answer (score 3):

You should ask your bank/broker's customer support.

Since the number is incomplete (rather than an incorrect but valid number) the transfer should fail. IBANs have two check digits to prevent this kind of error, so I'm a bit surprised you were able to submit the transfer at all.

Also, it looks like this question has been asked and answered before: [Incomplete IBAN used in bank transfer](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/91661/incomplete-iban-used-in-bank-transfer)

Comment: Using my experience on another site which has issues with answers in comments... Which bank to contact? (Presumably the sending bank) What information might they require? What has happened to the money in the meantime? All of these points enhance a simple answer.

Comment: @AndrewLeach all good points but I'd focus on improving the question first...

Comment: Since the linked prior question you linked had no answer [well, it contained comments with the correct answer], I marked that as a duplicate to this one; always wanted to create a time travel paradox!

Comment: Also - as to why this was allowed to release - depending on the form used by the asker to release the wire, it is possible that this was a relatively manual process [some banks still have paper wire request forms with a fax number to send to!], and it never actually 'released' at all, although the asker may have noticed the funds debited from their account by the bank, as the first stage of them sending out the wire. Reversal should be quite straightforward [at least, in banking-beauracracy terms].

Answer (score 0):

The bank will return the funds to your account if it cannot process the transfer.

If you are not sure what IBAN number to use, contact your bank and they will be able to help you.